# AngularJS $ViewContentLoaded: Any way to make it animate differently depending on UI-Router State?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My current solution forces Angular to use a jQuery animation to scroll to the top of the page on each `$viewContentLoaded`. It's simple and crude:

```
MyApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
    });
}]);
```

The problem comes with nested views in UI-Router, where it executes this code even though I don't want it to:

```
.state('review', {
    url: '/details/review',
    templateUrl: 'views/reviewsproduct.html',
    parent: 'detailedProduct',
    controller: 'ReviewController'
})
```

Is there a way to make it only animate (or not animate) when making specific state changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage listening to `$stateChangeSuccess` instead of `$viewContentLoaded`. You can target each `$state` and fire logic accordingly. Let's say you have a `$state` with a name of `foo` that you wish to fire your animation when navigating to...

```
MyApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if(toState.name === 'foo') {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
        }
    });
}]);
```

You can of course get granular with this and fire specific logic according to the `$state` you are transitioning to/from

> $stateChangeSuccess - fired once the state transition is complete.

See the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the link and information. I'll do it like this from now on.